# Unable to implement Social module in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: solr

I am currently working on configuring `Solr 8.1.1` in `Sitecore 9.3`,

In our `Sitecore 8.2 solution`, we found that there are some configs related to the `Social module` as listed below:

- Sitecore.Social.Solr.IndexConfiguration.config
- Sitecore.Social.Solr.Index.Web.config
- Sitecore.Social.Solr.Index.Master.config

When I try to configure the same in Sitecore 9.3, I am getting the below error:

> Could not find add method: AddExcludedField (type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration)
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
> Exception Details: Sitecore.Exceptions.RequiredObjectIsNullException: Could not find add method: AddExcludedField (type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration)
> Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configs you are asking here are related to Sitecore Social Connected module, for version 7.5 and previous it came as a separate module which you need to install but for Sitecore 8.0 to 8.2 it comes as part of Sitecore installation. But from Sitecore 9.0 and later Social Connected is not available and is not included in Sitecore.
See the [release notes of Sitecore 9.0](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/90/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2090%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes)
and [this link](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/81/sitecore-experience-platform/en/the-sitecore-social-connected-module.html)

I guess you are upgrading the Sitecore from version 8.2 to 9.3 so this feature will not be applicable for your upgraded Sitecore version and you need to remove it from the solution.

Answer (score 2):

By "Social Module", I assume you mean [Sitecore Social Connected](https://doc.sitecore.com/sdnarchive/Products/Social%20Connected%20Module.html)?

In which case the answer is simple. You cannot. Social Connected only supports Sitecore up to and including version 7.5.

Reference: [Sitecore modules compatibility table for Sitecore XP](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0541788)